# php var_dump returning blank array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm following this tutorial on youtube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VSF5p00uorc

Around 4:28 - I get the following array when I load the sql.php page as in the tutorial:

```
array(8) { [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL [3]=> NULL [4]=> NULL [5]=> NULL [6]=> NULL [7]=> NULL [8]=> NULL }
```

I do have 8 ids all with values in my data table. This is my code:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test2") or die('error');
$query = "select * from data";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = $row['id'];
    $feed = $row['feed'];
    $data[$id] = $feed;
}
var_dump($data);
?>
```

Comment: Define the array before you're filling values. `$data = array(); while(...)`

Comment: All you `feed` columns contain `NULL`? Would make the most sense ;) Or, you don't _have_ a `feed` column, but it's called something else, perhaps only whitespace or case-sensitive...

Comment: There is no scope issue here; while its best practice to initialize the array, it would not be the cause of the problem.

Comment: within the while loop, do a var_dump($row); and show us the output?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set error_reporting level like:
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

Looks like you have undefined offset 'feed' in your resultset.